# Deploying nodejs application to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am uploading nodeJs files on Heroku and after typing git commands, i get the link of my app but when, i am opening my app the i am getting application error - H20 and H10.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRj9T.jpg

Here is link of my project https://log-app-nodejs.herokuapp.com/
Please help me i tried a lot but i am not able to deploy my app to Heroku.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be using `nodemon` on Heroku. It is a _development_ tool, not a production tool. I suggest you also search for "app failed to bind to $port", there are plenty of other questions about this.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you're trying to deploy the backend of an application. In that case, this error does not necessarily means that your backend application is not up and running. It just has nothing to show you. Try making an API call to a function you may have created to insert/delete/ update data, through the URL provided to you.(You can do this through postman etc. or your frontend make sure you send the request to the URL, and not local host). If there is a change in your database, then your node.js application has been successfully deployed.